# ABOUT Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'where'

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, syntax, where-clause

```
 string sqlstr=string.Format("insert into ocs_outages(tt_id,out_date,description) values('{0}','{1}','{2}') where 'tt_id' not in (select tt_id from ocs_outages)",dr[1], Convert.ToDateTime(dr[3]).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"), dr[2]);
```

the bug is "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'where'."
what is this wrong in here? how to work it?

and the I need to tell user  update finish or fail to update .
what should I do ?
thanks to spend to read it. 
Forgive my poor English.

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks. For the sake of your users, *please* use [parameterized queries](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/Bb738521(v=VS.100).aspx).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why use `INSERT` statement with WHERE CLAUSE ?

`INSERT` is used to create a new Row

Use `UPDATE` query if you want to update any already created row.

**EDIT** : Try something like this

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE COLUMN = 'VALUE')
   INSERT INTO ocs_outages(tt_id,out_date,description) 
          VALUES('{0}','{1}','{2}')
```

Comment: Because this is a new data but I need to check it have existed in the datatable.

Comment: it's work!!!!thank you .
but how to tell user update success or fail